# Nonzero vector such that $Xv = av$ for some scalar $a$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $X$ such that $X = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\
10 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I go about finding the nonzero vector such that $Xv = av$ for some scalar $a$?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix (the eigenvalues are 1 and 2 - so we can find vectors for $a=1$ and $a=2$).
Another option would be to see from the form of the matrix that every vector of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is mapped to itself by the multiplication with the matrix.
Finding the vectors for $a=2$ is easy to find as well: Just solve $Xv=2v$ and you will find all vectors of the form $\begin{pmatrix} y \\ 10y \end{pmatrix}$